# sed command to change c-style multiline comments to c++ style multiline comments

Tags: regex, sed

This is the script:

```
sed 's\[/][*]\//\g ; s/[*][/]\s\+/\n/g ; s/[*][/]/\n/g' inputFile > outputFile
```

This is input file:

```
aaa /* bbb */ ccc /* ddd */ eee /* fff
ggg */ hhh /* iii */ jjj
kkk
/*  lll
    mmm
    nnn */
ooo
```

This is output file:

```
aaa // bbb 
ccc // ddd 
eee // fff
ggg 
hhh // iii 
jjj
kkk
//  lll
    mmm
    nnn 

ooo
```

Expected output:

```
aaa // bbb 
ccc // ddd 
eee // fff
// ggg 
hhh // iii 
jjj
kkk
//  lll
//  mmm
//  nnn 

ooo
```

The current script I using is unable to tackle with multiline comments, is there any way using sed command to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
perl -0777pe 's#/\*\s*(.+?)\s*\*/\s*#join("\n", map {"// " . $_ } split("\n", $1)) . "\n"#sge' inputFile
```

Output:

```
aaa // bbb
ccc // ddd
eee // fff
// ggg
hhh // iii
jjj
kkk
// lll
//     mmm
//     nnn
ooo
```

- The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp all lines at once.
- The `-pe` option enables the one-liner scripting.
- The `s` switch to the `s/pattern/replacement/` operator makes a dot match a newline character.
- The `e` switch to the `s/pattern/replacement/` operator enables the `replacement`
  to be a perl expression.
- The `join .. map .. split()` functions handle the multiline comments properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;\#/\*.*\*/#{s#/[*] ?#// #;s# \*/ ?#\n#;P;D};\#/\*#{N;s#(.* ?)\n#\1\n// #;ba}' file
```

If the current line contains both a starting and ending comment delimiter: replace the starting delimiter by `//` and the ending delimiter by `\n`, print the first line in the pattern space, remove it and then repeat.

Otherwise, if the current line contains a starting comment delimiter: append the following line, append `//` to the introduced newline and repeat (see above).

If there is no comment delimiters in the current line, print the line as normal.

N.B. The use of the alternate matching delimiter `\#...#` and the same for substitution `s#...#...#`, to avoid confusion because the comment delimiters contain `/`'s. The markdown may be acting up with the above solution owing to the nature of the `*`'s in the above text. Also for formatting purposes, spaces have been pinched and added to the result as per requirement.